# How can I choose the div to show and store as cookie or localstorage?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a basic dropdown options list - when clicking option it shall show a certain div (right now I add class to display and hide) - I get this to work but I must store the chosen option so on page refresh the option is still locked until user changes it. Can I use some cookie or something? I am pretty new to this "Explain like I'm 5 ;)" I appreciate any help. Thanks!

The selector:

```
    <li>
       <select id="song-gmt-selector">
                <option value="genres">Genres</option>
                <option value="moods">Moods</option>
                <option value="themes">Themes</option>
                <option value="instruments">Instruments</option>
            </select>
        </li>
```

Jquery I found:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#song-gmt-selector').on('change', function() {
        if ( this.value == 'genres')
        {
            $(".genres_s").addClass('show-gmt');
        }
        else
        {
            $(".genres_s").removeClass('show-gmt');
        }
        if ( this.value == 'moods')
        {
            $(".moods_s").addClass('show-gmt');
        }
        else
        {
            $(".moods_s").removeClass('show-gmt');
        }
        if ( this.value == 'themes')
        {
            $(".themes_s").addClass('show-gmt');
        }
        else
        {
            $(".themes_s").removeClass('show-gmt');
        }
        if ( this.value == 'themes')
        {
            $(".themes_s").addClass('show-gmt');
        }
        else
        {
            $(".themes_s").removeClass('show-gmt');
        }



    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var current = '';
            $('#song-gmt-selector').on('change', function () {
                current = $(this).val();
                console.log(current);
                $('.box').removeClass('show-gmt');
                $('.' + current + '_s').addClass('show-gmt');
                localStorage.setItem('current', current);
            });
            if (localStorage.getItem('current')) {
                $('#song-gmt-selector').val(localStorage.getItem('current'));
                $('.' + localStorage.getItem('current') + '_s').addClass('show-gmt');
            }
        });
```

HTML

```
<select id="song-gmt-selector">
    <option value="genres">Genres</option>
    <option value="moods">Moods</option>
    <option value="themes">Themes</option>
</select>

<div class="box genres_s">genres</div>
<div class="box moods_s">moods</div>
<div class="box themes_s">themes</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
   display: none;
 }
.box.show-gmt {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hey Lalji, thanks for your answer. I was just wondering what should the .box be?

Comment: The selector works nicely but it is not storing the option.It reverts to default (Genres) on new page